# Are moduli of components of Fourier transformed Gaussian random vector still independent?

Tags: normal-distribution, independence, fourier-transform, random-vector

Suppose $X=[X_1,\ldots, X_n]^T$ is a random (column) vector such that:

- $X_i \stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2), \  1 \le i \le n$
- $\mathcal{F} \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is the [discrete Fourier transform matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix)
- $Z=[Z_1,\ldots,Z_n]^T:= \mathcal{F}X$
- $A=[A_1,\ldots,A_n]^T:= [Z_1 \bar{Z_1},\ldots,Z_n \bar{Z_n}]^T$, where $\bar Z_i$ is the complex conjugate of $Z_i$

then are the random variables $\lbrace A_1,\ldots,A_n\rbrace$ still mutually independent?

UPDATE: As per @whuber's comment below we have,

1. $Z_i$'s are [joint normally distributed](https://almostsuremath.com/2021/02/24/multivariate-normal-distributions/)
2. [A joint normal pair of random variables are independent if and only if their covariance is zero](https://almostsuremath.com/2021/03/24/independence-of-normals/)

Comment: @mhdadk I'm looking for a starting point.  The fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is complex makes things a bit more difficult.

Comment: If the $Z_i$ are independent then so will be the $A_i$ (and if the $A_i$ are not independent then the $Z_i$ aren't either, but that takes a little effort to show). With Gaussian variables (complex or not), orthogonality (zero covariance) is equivalent to independence.  So: compute the covariance matrix of $Z.$

Comment: @whuber thank you. The last sentence is what I needed. Yet again, you're a life saver.